# Adding external .rcc files into Android assets in CMake Qt6

Tags: android, qt, cmake, qt6, rcc

I'm trying to put some image files in an external .rcc binary file, adding this resource file in the app using `QResource::registerResource()` to be able to access the images.

The .rcc file is correctly generated and it works great in desktop.
But I don't know how to bundle the external .rcc files into the Android package built by QtCreator.

In my `CMakeLists.txt` I have that to create the .rcc file:

```
# creating the 'MyModule' qml module in my app
qt_add_qml_module(MyModule
    ...
    # I don't want to use RESOURCES here because I want them to be in a separate binary file
)

# creating the target 'images' which will compile the images.qrc into images.rcc
qt_add_binary_resources(images images.qrc)

# making the qrc file discoverable by QtCreator
target_sources(images PRIVATE images.qrc)

# adding the target images as a dependency to build it when the module is built
add_dependencies(MyModule images)
```

I know I could manually copy the .rcc file from the build directory into the [`${ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR}/assets`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-platform-notes.html#assets-file-system) folder and rerun the build from Qt Creator.
This is working fine, but it's not a viable solution.

Is there a way to automatically add the generated external .rcc files into the android package `assets` folder?

*(I don't necessarily search for a cross-platform solution, but an android specific one)*